# How to show that the singularity of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{nx}$ at $x=0$ is a simple pole of order 1?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, asymptotics

Consider the function

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{nx} = -\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{12}x \ +\dots  $$

There is an elementary "trick" to show this has as simple pole of order 1 which is equating $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{nx}$  with $\frac{1}{1-e^x}$ and then carrying out a laurent expansion of this. But i'm not really interested in this trick. Instead just I want to work explicitly with the series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{nx} = 1 + e^x + e^{2x} + e^{3x} + ... $$

And prove that the pole at $x=0$ is of order 1 directly. So a first start would be to just guess the pole has order one and then consider the expression:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} \left[  x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{nx} \right] $$

Evaluating this directly leads to the expression $0 \times \infty $ which is indeterminate.

Trying to use L'Hopitals doesn't seem to be of much help either:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left[  x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{nx} \right]  = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{nx}}{\frac{1}{x}}$$

As you just end up differentiating the top and bottom expressions indefinitely.

Expanding as a taylor series isn't useful EITHER because the expansions come out to

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{nx} = 1 + (1 + 1 + 1 ... ) + (1 + 2 + 3 + ... ) x + \frac{1}{2!} (1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... )x^2 + ... $$

Even if you knew about the Riemann Zeta function AND could account for shifting in the series you would INCORRECTLY conclude

$$  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{nx} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{12}x  + \ ... $$

And miss that singularity entirely.

So now that motivates a very natural question. Using simple first principles for real and complex analysis at the undergraduate level. How do you actually conclude that this series has a pole of order 1?

### One More Idea:

We need to consider $$ \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left[ x \sum_{n=0}^{k} e^{nx} \right] $$

We need to find an explicit sequence $x_n \rightarrow 0$ and $k_n \rightarrow \infty$ such that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta$ s.t.  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n > \delta$

$$ \left| \left[ x_n \sum_{i=0}^{k_n} e^{ix_n} \right] - 1 \right| < \epsilon $$

Comment: the series $\sum_{k\geqslant 0}e^{kz}$ clearly diverges when $z>0$, therefore $z=0$ can't be a pole as the function is not defined at any neighborhood to the right of zero

Comment: What about just multiplying by $x$ and showing the limit is nonzero as $x\to0$? With the series expression at the top, that much is “clear” and then it must be a pole of order $1$.

Comment: Its not obvious to me that $x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{nx} \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ from the left. I want to actually name an explicit sequence $x_n$ and $k_n$ for the sum so I can actually show that $\epsilon$-inequality. Directly evaluating the limit seems to have failed in my work above.

Comment: @Masacroso is there a definition for a pole-like-object even when you don't have neighborhoods?

Comment: @Masacroso something something analytic continuation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you'd basically like a proof that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} \left[  x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{nx} \right]$ exists and is finite and nonzero, *without* using the geometric series formula.

This limit will look less confusing after a change of variables $r = e^x$, getting $\lim_{r \to 1^-} \ln(r) \sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n$. At this point we can once again see that it'll be easy to proceed if we used the geometric series formula, but that's not allowed! Instead, let $f(r) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n$ and use l'Hopital's rule:

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{r \to 1^-} \ln(r) f(r) &= \lim_{r \to 1^-} \frac{\ln(r)} {\frac 1 {f(r)}} \\
&= \lim_{r \to 1^-} \frac{1/r}{-f'(r) f(r)^{-2}} \\
&= -\lim_{r \to 1^-} \left(\frac{1}{r}\right) \frac{f(r)^2}{f'(r)}
\end{align}
$$

We can separately compute $$f(r)^2 = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n\right)^2 = (1+r+r^2+r^3+\cdots)^2 = 1 + 2r + 3r^2 + \cdots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n-1) r^n$$

$$f'(r) = \frac{d}{dr} \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n \right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n-1) r^{n-1}$$

so $f(r)^2 = f'(r)$ and thus our limit above just becomes $-\lim_{r \to 1^-} \left( \frac 1 r \right)$ which is $-1$. As desired, this is finite and nonzero, meaning that $x^1$ really was the correct power to multiply by at the start.

---

For simplicity, I skipped justifying a couple of steps above.

When simplifying $f(r)^2$ I "multiplied two power series together in the obvious way". This is actually valid at any point within the radius of convergence of both series ([source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255105/multiplication-of-complex-power-series)) but it's not trivial.

Second, when simplifying $f'(r)$ I "swapped the order of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$ and $\frac d {dr}$". Again this is true within the radius of convergence, but again it's not trivial; here's a [source](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Complex_Power_Series).

Comment: Ah thats clever with the change of variables.

Comment: @Masacroso The limit you just typed is a one-sided limit as $r \to 1^-$, so the behaviour for $r > 1$ is not relevant here. Throughout this answer I'm only working with values $|r| < 1$, for exactly the reason you're worried about.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly silly answer. Note that

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x} = 1$$

and so

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} x \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{nx}&=\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} (e^x - 1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{nx} &&\text{(by the multiplication rule for limits)}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0^-} \left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{nx}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{nx}\right]&&\text{(multiplying the two factors)}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0^-} e^{0x}&&\text{(canceling like terms from each sum)}\\
&= 1
\end{align*}

(Why is this silly? Because the only reason we're not using the geometric series formula is that we're actually proving it!)

Comment: I think this might be legit because the limit you presented in the beginning doesn't depend on the definition of the geometric series